# Best strategy for reading multiple large csv files in python with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am writing some code and hoping to improve it with multiprocessing.

Originally, I had the following code:

```py
with Pool() as p:
        lst = p.map(self._path_to_df, paths)
...
df = pd.concat(lst, ignore_index=True)
```

where `self._path_to_df()` basically just calls `pandas.read_csv(...)` and returns a pandas DataFrame.

Which results in the following error:

```
.
.
.
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[                    ts                  id.orig  ...  successful history_category
0         1.331901e+09               ...        True            other
1         1.331901e+09               ...        True                ^
2         1.331901e+09               ...        True               Sh
3         1.331901e+09               ...        True               Sh
4         1.331901e+09               ...        True               Sh
...                ...               ...         ...              ...
23192090  1.332018e+09               ...       False            other
23192091  1.332017e+09               ...        True            other
23192092  1.332018e+09               ...        True            other
23192093  1.332018e+09               ...        True            other
23192094  1.332018e+09               ...        True            other

[23192095 rows x 24 columns]]'. Reason: 'error("'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647")'
```

The error is from one of the files it's reading being too large for `self._path_to_df()` to return the DataFrame of while using multiprocessing.

There are potentially multiple files of varying sizes (small to very big 3GB+) involved so I was trying to figure out what is the best way to use multiprocessing for this task.

Should I somehow chunk all the data so that `p.map()` can work or is that too much overhead? If so, how would I do that? Should I use multiprocessing in the reading of each file and look at each file sequentially?

Edit: Additionally, it doesn't seem to error when it's only smaller files involved

Comment: You really do not want to return a DataFrame from a subprocess to the main process as this will cause the DataFrame to be pickled, which will be very slow. If reading your CSV is really that slow, you could read it in chunks in subprocesses and still in the subprocess write to disk with a fast format (feather might be a good one), then read in the multiple feather files in the main process.

Comment: Does this problem occur with multiprocessing.dummy.Pool? This will help to see if the issue is with the serialization of the data frames. I think overall that Dask is a better fit for your needs than Pool (https://dask.org/). It's more or less designed for this problem.

Comment: @fizzybear the truncated part of the traceback only excludes my own files so multiprocessing.pool.py I think

Answer (score 0):

If the end result is too large to fit into memory try dask,

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('*.csv')
```

then once it is read, you can do your aggregates, etc. and finally compute to get your desired answer.